# Selector for First-Element after Sibiling Text?

Tags: css

In this HTML Structure:

```html
<div>
  <span>A</span>
  <span>B</span>
  C
  <span>D</span>
  <span>E</span>
</div>
```

I want to make the `element` after the `C` to get the `color: red;`, So I want the letter `D` to be `red`.

Is that possible?

Comment: is the HTML dynamic ? if not simply do this `span:nth-child(3)`

Comment: @TemaniAfif Yes, it is Dynamic, it could be `B` text next or `A`, depends on the page.

Comment: if it's dynamic then I don't think you can do with pure CSS, you need some JS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the HTML structure is not static you cannot rely on CSS to do this, you will need some JS.

Here is an idea where I target text node and wrap them within a span with a specific class then you can easily adjust the style using CSS.

*I used jQuery for simplicity to show the idea, we can do this with only JS*

```js
$(".container").contents().filter(function () {
    return this.nodeType === 3 && this.nodeValue.trim() !== "";
}).wrap("<span class='text-node'></span>");
```

```css
.text-node + * {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <span>A</span>
  <span>B</span>
  C
  <span>D</span>
  <span>E</span>
  F
  <span>G</span>
  <span>H</span>
  <span>I</span>
</div>
```